# SQL select row data as individual columns

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to get a database query back that has some inputs from one table and some from a another table. I know how to do this but my problem is in my query I have to get values from this table:

```
AID | Meet | Event | Score
--------------------------
1   | Val  | Beam  | 9.47
1   | Snow | Beam  | 7.78
```

I need to get the score values from the snow meet and the val meet separately so my out put query will look like this:

```
AID | SnowScore | ValScore
--------------------------
1   | 7.78      | 9.47
```

I am just very confused on where to start here. Sorry if this is confusing it is very hard to describe. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is it always only "Snow" and "Val" and will AID always be 1?

Answer (score 1):

This type of result is pretty roundabout. You have to query each Column separately.

Try this:

```
SELECT s.AID, s.Score AS SnowScore, v.Score as ValScore
FROM tbl s INNER JOIN tbl v ON (s.AID = v.AID)
WHERE s.Meet = "Snow" AND v.Meet = "Val";
```

if the column "Score" is nullable, you have to work with outer join instead of inner join.

If there are more than exactly one Score for each AID and Meet, you also may consider an aggregate function and a group by AID-clause.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38733)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(AID INT,  Meet VARCHAR(10), [Event] VARCHAR(10),Score DECIMAL(10,2))

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1 , 'Val'  , 'Beam' ,9.47),
(1 , 'Snow' , 'Beam' ,7.78),
(2 , 'Val'  , 'Beam' ,9.50),
(2 , 'Snow' , 'Beam' ,7.50)


SELECT AID 
      ,Snow AS SnowScore
      ,Val  AS ValScore
FROM @TABLE T
PIVOT (SUM(Score)
       FOR Meet
       IN (Snow, Val)
       )p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38733/0)**:

```
| AID | SNOWSCORE | VALSCORE |
|-----|-----------|----------|
|   1 |      7.78 |     9.47 |
|   2 |       7.5 |      9.5 |
```

### Database Generic Query

```
SELECT AID 
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Meet = 'Val' THEN Score ELSE NULL END) AS ValScore
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Meet = 'Snow' THEN Snow ELSE NULL END) AS SnowScore
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY AID
```

Comment: Where are you getting SQL Server?

Comment: Why not just provide an answer that works for all DBs instead of something specific to one?  That could easily be done with a CASE/aggregate which IMO would be better than guessing.